# What is the least amount of time for visible corrosion build up on a motherboard

Tags: motherboard, corrosion

I am wondering how long it takes for visible corrosion to build up on a laptop's motherboard ?

I have bought a new sealed laptop from a reseller of a well-known manufacturer.
After very short time of using it, I found out that the laptop's motherboard had signs of corrosion on it.
Which suggests that the device must have been water damaged previously.

Assuming I only actively had the laptop in use for less than 12h, is it possible that corrosion can build up on the motherboard and inside it's hdmi ports like that ?
It had a thick white greenish looking powder on these parts.

Comment: How reliable is the reseller? What assurances of quality do they offer? Do they have product guarantees? Buying a 2nd-hand PCB is just the same as buying a 2nd-hand resistor, transistor, capacitor, diode, chip etc. but probably more risky so, the motivation for buying it must have been based on something. I can't get motivated to buy any 2nd-hand piece of electronics so, what was yours?

Comment: Be careful: The greenish powder is most likely cupric acetate, which is poisonous, so handle with care.

Comment: Heat shrink tunnels are cheap compared to the profit to be had by selling re-sealed packages as "sealed" (as opposed to "factory sealed").  Of if the seller considers her basement as a factory maybe they'll finesse the description too.

Comment: did you pour water on the laptop? if not, then it takes a very very long time

Comment: @SpehroPefhany There was one large retailer here in Silicon Valley who was famous for taking returned electronics defective or not, re-shrink wrapping it and putting it back on the shelf on the theory that if it was defective someday somebody would be too lazy to return it.  (Or in hope that it wasn't actually defective.) I found a board that I had returned that was clearly defective on the shelf to be sold again a few days later. (It was in a clear bag hanging on a hook, so I could see the exact defect that I returned it for.)  Caveat emptor!

Comment: Hours is quite possible if powered up while wet, thanks to electrolysis, if there is some contamination to make the water or condensation conductive. I've certainly seen vias fail thanks to corrosion on that timescale. For example, was it cold when you unsealed it, in a warm moist atmosphere?

Answer (score 1):

Corrosion can occur in a very short time on a circuit board that is both wet and powered. A board can be underwater for quite a while, weeks, maybe months and not suffer significant corrosion, but when there is voltage on the board electrolysis occurs which will corrode the copper conductors, and it can happen in a matter of minutes. I've seen electronic equipment that had severe green corrosion within 1/2 hour of liquid being spilled in it. This is why it is recommended to immediately remove all power sources from any electronic equipment that gets wet.

Answer (score 0):

No, that mustn't happen in such a short time period. That mainboard must have been either directly exposed to water or in an area with very high humidity. In theory, it could also be a manufacturing error (missing sealant on the PCB) but it's unlikely that wouldn't be noticed.

I do have some (small) PCBs in operation that are more or less constantly exposed to water and they do corode, but not this fast. It may take a season or so to really look bad and eventually break.